# how can i make all sprites move to different attraction points using p5.js /p5.play

Tags: p5.js, p5.play

I am creating a game and have sprites falling from the top of the canvas and destroying towers at the bottom of the canvas. I am trying to use `attractionPoint` on all the different towers so the sprites are moving towards the towers. I have currently gotten one sprite to move to a tower using `attactionPoint` but the remaining sprites continue to move in a straight path. Is there a way I am able to set multiple attraction points so the sprites are moving toward all towers?

see code below:

```js
function createAsteroids() {
  // code to spawn asteroids at random locations

  for (let i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
    asteroid = createSprite(random(0, 1000), random(-50, -350), 40, 40);
    asteroid.maxSpeed = random(1, 3);
    rock.add(asteroid);
    asteroidArray.push(asteroid);
  }
}

function drawAsteroid() {
  // draws asteroids moving down and checking collision
  rock.overlap(turret, explode);
  for (let i = 0; i < asteroidArray.length; i++) {
    if (asteroidArray[i].position.y > height) {
      asteroidArray[i].position.y = 0;
      asteroidArray[i].position.x = random(0, 800);
    }
    asteroidArray[i].addSpeed(3, 90);
    asteroid.attractionPoint(1, 100, 740);
    asteroid.attractionPoint(1, 400, 740);
    asteroid.attractionPoint(1, 700, 740);
  }
}

function explode(sprite, obstical) {
  //code for explosion and collision
  sprite.remove();
  obstical.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close but there's a couple things that aren't quite correct. In `drawAsteroid` you're setting the `attractionPoint` on only the lastly created asteroid, and doing it 3 times and calling it - i assume - in the draw method so it would get updated each frame. We only really want the `drawAsteroid` function for its respawning logic, so let's rename this method to `updateAsteroid` rather than `drawAsteroid` because we're going to call `drawSprites(rock);` in the draw method (rock is the group you've created for your asteroids).

When we set the `attractionPoint` we only want to do that once and that's when we create the asteroid:

```js
function createAsteroids() {
  // code to spawn asteroids at random locations
  for (let i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
    let asteroid = createSprite(random(0, width), random(-50, -350), 40, 40);
    asteroid.maxSpeed = random(1, 3);
    rock.add(asteroid);
    
    let tower = floor(random(3))  // i know there's only 3 asteroids, you could do something better here
    
    asteroid.attractionPoint(asteroid.maxSpeed, towers[tower].position.x, towers[tower].position.y);
  }
}
```

So we're just randomly targeting a tower from the group.

I've set up a small example that should point you in the right direction.

```js
// Find my blog at https://codeheir.com/
// I do a lot of p5.js stuff that might interest you!

let numAsteroids = 10;
let towers;
let rock;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  rock = Group();
  towers = Group();
  createTowers();
  createAsteroids();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  drawSprites(rock);
  drawSprites(towers);
  updateAsteroids();

}

function createAsteroids() {
  // code to spawn asteroids at random locations
  for (let i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++) {
let asteroid = createSprite(random(0, width), random(-50, -350), 40, 40);
asteroid.maxSpeed = random(1, 3);
rock.add(asteroid);

let tower = floor(random(3))

asteroid.attractionPoint(asteroid.maxSpeed, towers[tower].position.x, towers[tower].position.y);
  }
}


function updateAsteroids() {
  // draws asteroids moving down and checking collision
  //rock.overlap(turret, explode);
  for (let i = 0; i < rock.length; i++) {
if (rock[i].position.y > height) {
  rock[i].position.y = 0;
  rock[i].position.x = random(0, width);
}
  }
}

function createTowers() {
  towers.push(createSprite(40, height - 30, 40, 90));
  towers.push(createSprite(width/2, height - 30, 40, 90));
  towers.push(createSprite(width-40, height - 30, 40, 90));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/molleindustria/p5.play/lib/p5.play.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've also created a [p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/UTu11c5H_) to point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, soo much for your answer luke, was really helpful and just what I was after. i will definitely look at your blog for more p5 content. thankyou